# youtube video upload with uploadify and paperclip custom processor ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, youtube, paperclip, uploadify

I have a file uploader that currently uploads images / pdf with a nice progress bar using uploadify and saves to S3 using paperclip.

I want to upload videos the same way but instead of to s3, i want to save to youtube.

Is there a processor or something that i can use to save to youtube ?

Would i be able to see the progress via the progress bar ?  would this show all the progress of uploading it straight to youtube ?

Or is there a better way ?   I dont want to store videos or convert them myself.

thanks alot for the help in advance
rick

Comment: Why do you want to upload youtube videos? I think you should save a reference to the video (youtube video_id) and then manipulate the resource through the youtube api using a gem (e.g http://github.com/tmm1/youtube-g)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to create a post processor that takes the video and uses the YouTube Data API direct uploading method to upload the file:

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Direct_uploading

If you want to see the progress bar you have to upload the file to your server before sending it to youtube,  and it will only reflect the progress of uploading it to your intermediate site (too much work for the sake of showing a progress bar, if you ask me), otherwise you can send the file straight to youtube and I don't think you'll see any progress bar, but you won't waste double bandwidth. In any of this cases I don't think you'll need to worry about converting the file yourself as long as the format is supported by youtube.